# Yii2 не отображается Debug панель

Tags: yii2

Установил модуль через `composer`, настроил как указано в документации.
В коде страницы вроде как панель есть, но на самой странице не отображается.
В консоли ошибка.

```
 http://black.open/debug/default/toolbar?tag=5e25fcd327073 404 (Not Found)
```

У панели стиль `display:none` в ней,

```
<pre>Not Found: Unable to find debug data tagged with &#039;5e2600cd7340e&#039;.</pre>
```

Сайт доступен по адресу `http://black.open/`, ЧПУ ссылки работают.

Куда смотреть?

Конфиг такой.

```
return [
    'id' => 'scool',
    'basePath' => realpath( __DIR__ . '/../'),
    'bootstrap' => [
        'debug' 
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm' => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'components' => [
            'urlManager' => [
                    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                    'showScriptName' => false
            ],
            'request' => [
                    'cookieValidationKey' => 'sadWADwdwdWD2e123'
            ],
    ],
    'modules' => [
            'debug' => [
                    'class' =>'yii\debug\Module',
                    'allowedIPs'=>['*']
            ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучив логи сервера обнаружил другие ошибки которые вывели на то, что не подключено.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```